# JAVA implementar el método sin parámetros invocando el método correspondiente con parámetros

Tags: java

**Buenas! En la tarea me pide hacer dos métodos de comprar y vender entradas. Dejo el enunciado!**

Para representar la realización de la compra de entradas de la obra que se está representando implementaremos dos métodos:

- El método comprarEntradas, que recibirá como parámetro el número de entradas que se quieren comprar.
- El método comprarEntrada, que no recibirá ningún parámetro y que realizará la compra de una sola entrada.
  Debes tener en cuenta que si un teatro no tiene ninguna obra asignada no debería poderse comprar ninguna entrada, lanzándose una excepción de tipo IllegalStateException con el mensaje de error "El teatro no tiene una obra asignada, por tanto no se pueden comprar entradas".

Si se intenta comprar un número de entradas que supere el aforo tampoco se permitirá, lanzándose una excepción de tipo IllegalStateException con el mensaje de error "El número de entradas supera el aforo, no pueden aumentarse las entradas".

Además, si se intenta comprar un número de entradas negativo o cero tampoco se permitirá, lanzándose una excepción de tipo IllegalArgumentException con el mensaje de error "No se pueden comprar xxx entradas", donde xxx representa el número de entradas que se han intentado comprar. Por ejemplo, si se intentaran comprar -3 entradas, el mensaje de error sería "No se pueden comprar -3 entradas".

Si se ha podido realizar la compra de entradas, estos métodos tendrán que actualizar apropiadamente los atributos de objeto y de clase necesarios para representar que se ha llevado a cabo la compra. Ten en cuenta que para implementar el método sin parámetros deberás realizar una invocación al método correspondiente con parámetros para de esa manera evitar al máximo la redundancia de código y los peligros que ello conlleva.

En mi código me falta el comprarEntradas sin parámetro que no se de donde sacar el this. Adjunto el código y espero su ayuda. Muchas gracias

```
public void comprarEntradas (int Entradas)throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException {
   
   
   if (NombreTeatro.contains(Obra)){
       throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada, por tanto no se pueden comprar entradas");}
   
   if (Entradas >= AFORO_MAX){
       throw new IllegalStateException ("El numero de entradas supera el aforo, no pueden aumentarse las entradas");}
   
   if (Entradas <= 0 ){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException ("No se pueden comprar"+ Entradas + "entradas");}
  
   this.Entradas = ++ EntradasVendidas;
   this.EntradasVendidas = ++EntradasVendidasTotales;       
    
    }



public void comprarEntradas(){
   
   this();
```

Comment: En comprarEntradas() (sin parametros) llama a ComprarEntradas(1), nada más.

Comment: Para que te quede claro: `public void comprarEntradas(){ comprarEntradas(1)}` solo eso tienes que hacer

Comment: muchas gracias! pero me podeis explicar porque es (1)

Comment: Y si hago el nombre.contais(obra) bien? quiero hacer que si un teatro no tiene ninguna obra asignada no debería poderse comprar ninguna entrada

Comment: Hola @antonio, la idea detrás de llamar al metodo con parámetros desde el que no los tiene, es lo que te pide el profe, no escribir código redundante, usas comprarEntradas() como una forma de determinar la cantidad de estas, y el resto del código lo usas de comprarEntradas( int entradas ).

Comment: Cuidado, en el primer if, la condición es ( NombreTeatro.contains(Obra) ), osea, si el teatro tiene obra, te arroja una excepción, y debe hacer lo contrario, debes negar la condición, ( ! NombreTeatro.contains(Obra) ), los otros if están perfectos, por otro lado no me queda claro, porque tienes Entradas y EntradasVendidas, creo que con entradasVendidas y aforo, alcanza, y más, si la varible EntradasVendidas la tienes declarada en el cuerpo de la clase, el this sale sobrando, dentro del cuerpo de comprarEntradas(), this(); está de más.

Comment: ahora me ha petado el código... he puesto otro post, porfa ayudadme. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577207/java-metodos-comprar-vender-entradas-da-error

Comment: @antonio, como te dicen en el otro post, necesitamos ver el método main, y cual es la variable "s", y por supuesto que, en lo que pueda, te ayudaré.

Comment: @MarcePuente https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577230/java-metodo-no-realiza-lo-pedido este es el post, lo siento y muchas gracias