# JAVA Metodo no realiza lo pedido

Tags: java

con el tema del comprar vender entradas no encuentro solución! Ahora no me salta ningun error, pero no me da valores, se queda en 0 o null. En mi código es la parte que yo voy escribiendo, que luego se ejecuta en otro archivo java que esta realizado por el profesor que es el main y el ultimo código es utilidades que también lo da el profesor para que se ejecute mi codigo.

Mi código

```
 public void comprarEntradas (int Entradas) throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException {
   
   
   if (!nombreTeatro.contains(Obra)){
       throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada, por tanto no se pueden comprar entradas");}
       
   
   if (this.Entradas >= AFORO_MAX){
       throw new IllegalStateException ("El numero de entradas supera el aforo, no pueden aumentarse las entradas");}
   
   if (this.Entradas <= 0 ){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException ("No se pueden comprar"+ Entradas + "entradas");}
  
   this.Entradas = ++ EntradasVendidas;
   this.EntradasVendidas = ++EntradasVendidasTotales;}



public void comprarEntrada(){ comprarEntradas(1);} 
   
  //DEVOLVERENTRADAS ES LO MISMO PERO LO HE OMITIDO PARA VER MAS FACIL
   
   public void vaciarTeatro ()throws IllegalStateException {
       
       if (!nombreTeatro.contains(Obra)){
           throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada, por tanto no puede vaciarse");}
       
       if (EntradasVendidas <= 0 ){
           throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene entradas vendidas para esa obra, por tanto no puede vaciarse");}
       
       this.EntradasVendidas = --EntradasVendidasTotales;
      }
   
   public void llenarTeatro() throws IllegalStateException{
       
       if (!nombreTeatro.contains(Obra)){
           throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro no tiene una obra asignada, por tanto no puede llenarse");}
       
       if (EntradasVendidas > Teatro.AFORO_MAX){
           throw new IllegalStateException ("El teatro ya esta completo para esa obra, por tanto no puede llenarse.");}}
```

El código main en el que corre tiene esto:

```
Utilidades.devolverEntradasTeatro(teatro1,4); //Error: No hay tantas entradas vendidas en este teatro
```

(Asi en las distintas veces)

Y el código de utilidades, es el que me dan por defecto en el ejercicio. Yo lo que tengo que hacer es en el código primero que son las que estoy haciendo yo implementar las utilidades para que vaya bien la prueba que es el main.

```
public static void comprarEntradasTeatro(Teatro miTeatro, int entradas) {
    StringBuilder consulta = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        consulta.append(cabecera(String.format("Intentando comprar %d entradas para la obra \"%s\" en el teatro \"%s\"", entradas, miTeatro.tieneObra() ? miTeatro.getObra() : "---", miTeatro.getNombreTeatro())) );
        miTeatro.comprarEntradas(entradas);
        consulta.append("Compra realizada con éxito.\n");
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        consulta.append(String.format("Error. %s\n", ex.getMessage()) );
    } finally {
        consulta.append(String.format("Número de entradas vendidas para la obra actual: %d\n", miTeatro.getEntradasVendidas()));
        consulta.append(String.format("Número de entradas vendidas totales: %d\n", Teatro.getEntradasVendidasTotales()));
    }
    System.out.print(consulta);
 }
 
public static void comprarEntradaTeatro(Teatro miTeatro) {
     StringBuilder consulta = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        consulta.append(cabecera(String.format("Intentando comprar 1 entrada para la obra \"%s\" en el teatro \"%s\"", miTeatro.tieneObra() ? miTeatro.getObra() : "---", miTeatro.getNombreTeatro())) );
        miTeatro.comprarEntrada();
        consulta.append("Compra realizada con éxito.\n");
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        consulta.append(String.format("Error. %s\n", ex.getMessage()) );
    } finally {
        consulta.append(String.format("Número de entradas vendidas para la obra actual: %d\n", miTeatro.getEntradasVendidas()));
        consulta.append(String.format("Número de entradas vendidas totales: %d\n", Teatro.getEntradasVendidasTotales()));
    }
    System.out.print(consulta);
}
 

Y devolver entradas lo mismo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void comprarEntradas( int Entradas ) throws IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException {
    if( !NombreTeatro.contains( "Obra" ) ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "El teatro no tiene una obra asignada, por tanto no se pueden comprar entradas" );
    }
    if( EntradasVendidas >= AFORO_MAX ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "El numero de entradas supera el aforo, no pueden aumentarse las entradas" );
    }
    if( Entradas <= 0 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "No se pueden comprar" + Entradas + "entradas" );
    }
    EntradasVendidas += Entradas;
    EntradasVendidasTotales += Entradas;
}  

public void comprarEntrada() {
    comprarEntradas( 1 );
}

public int getEntradasVendidas() {
    return EntradasVendidas;
}

public int getEntradasVendidasTotales() {
    return EntradasVendidasTotales;
}

public boolean tieneObra() {
    return Obra != null;
}

public String getObra() {
    return Obra;
}

public String getNombreTeatro() {
    return NombreTeatro;
}
```

Hice algunas correciones, los errores que tenía, se derivan del uso de nombres repetidos, por eso insisto (y tu lo aplicas si quieres), olvidate de this, desaparece la variable Entrada que no tiene razón de ser y cambia el nombre del parámetro recibido por el método a entradasPedidas.
El primer if está bien, en el segundo verifica contra Entradas, y debería hacerlo con entradasVendidas, el tercero tiene que verificar que el parámetro recibido, osea la cantidad de entradas a comprar sea mayor que cero, y en realidad lo que haces es verificar Entradas (de la clase), que no es lo que se busca.

Comment: Hola @antonio, a tu profe (y a nosotros) se le ha pasado crear una excepción para el caso en que no haya más entradas vendidas que aforo, pero que la suma de entradas vendidas más compradas si supere a aforo, que devolvería un mensaje tipo "No disponemos de n entradas, solo nos quedan n1".

Comment: Sigue el código sin hacer nada, se ejecuta pero no realiza nada sigue en 0 @MarcePuente

Comment: en el enunciado nos pide que el parámetro pedido sea int Entradas

Comment: además cuando se ejecuta el código, en el lugar de obra, me sale "---" como si no tuviera el nombre, que en el ejemplo si sale

Comment: @antonio, volvi a poner **Entradas** y agregué los métodos que faltaban, en la clase **Teatro**, paso a paso...

Comment: creo que el problema es que me sale al ejecutarlo "el teatro no tiene una obra asignada, " entonces creo que el problema viene que no se le asigna la obra al teatro. ademas yo tengo puesto entradasVendidas como static, y si lo quito al ejecutarlo me pone error por" cannot be referenced from a static context "

Comment: @antonio, exacto, en el código de utilidades, debes primero instaciar la clase Teatro, algo como **Teatro miTeatro = new Teatro();** y luego asignarle una obra, **miTeatro.setObra( "La casa embrujada" ),**, eso te obliga a escribir el correspondiente seter en la clase Teatro.

Comment: ¿Que es lo que sigue en 0? Al parecer tu clase Teatro tiene las propiedades Entradas, EntradasVendidas y EntradasVendidasTotales ¿Cual es la diferencia porque EntradasVendidas parece ser igual a EntradasVendidasTotales? Si en Obra te sale "---" entonces el objeto Teatro está mal creado o porque no tiene obra o el flag tieneObra sigue no cambió a true. En el método ComprarEntradasTeatro(Teatro miTeatro) debería tener soló una linea: ComprarEntradasTeatro(miTeatro,1); es decir llamar al otro método.

Comment: En el if de aforo la condición debería ser (EntradasVendidasTotales + Entradas)>AFORO_MAX. y tu condición Entradas<=0 debería ir primero que la de AFORO.

Comment: Aparte que deberías poner todo el código. Ahora si lo hacen de a pedazos una parte tu y otra parte el profe entonces ese es el principal problema